# Is compressing groups of uncompressable yet very similar files possible?

Tags: zip, gzip, winrar

I have a number of files 15 GB+ in size and non of them can be compressed as the content is an encrypted container.

I have many of these files where only a slight different exists between them, so 90%+ of the data is common.

Using *WinRAR* I can set a dictionary size of 1 GB, but I believe this means only 1 GB of the 15 GB thats common to each file will be efficiently compressed. So two files equals 29 GB best case.

Does any software exist to compress multiple large and similar files.

Comment: Consider accepting answers that are helpful. 

To accept an answer click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer that is best, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)  See [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more detail.

Also please consider going back and accepting past answers, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)

Answer (score 0):

If the files are correctly encrypted there will be no similarity in the encrypted data. A properly encrypted file is indistinguishable from random data.

If there is any similarity, even small sections, between the files the encryption incorrect and compromised. If an encryption mode such as ECB or CTR mode with the same key and nonce.

Note: If there are repeats in the encrypted data that leaks information about the underlying data, that is in general a security problem.

Comment: Let me clarify, I have an encrypted container. I copies the container and made some changes to some files inside it. The rest of the container, except the FAT will be the same. I am saying that the two slightly different copies of the container, rather then the container itself.

Comment: Essentially the same answer. One way is to treat the container's encryption in segments that are each individually encrypted. This is what is often done for whole disk (in your case container) encryption. In the disk case generally each sector is individually encrypted with key or key/iv pair that contains the sector number as a component. So each sector is uniquely and individually encrypted. There are encryption modes and schemes such as XTS. For more info on XTS see [Why do we use XTS](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14628/why-do-we-use-xts-over-ctr-for-disk-encryption). ...

Comment: ...  Note that XTS mode may or not be a secure solution in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Solid compression of *WinRAR* works different as you think. The dictionary size is just a memory space allocated for compressing similar **small** files used dynamically for each file.

For example I have a folder with 366 files. 30 files are text files with less than 12 KB. The others are binary files with a file size between 40 KB and 450 KB. Total size of all files is 48 MB. Solid compression with a dictionary size of just 4 MB with correct configured `RarFiles.lst` for those files results in a RAR archive with just 205 KB using RAR4 format. Most files are stored with less than 500 bytes in the archive including header for the file as it can be seen on opening the RAR archive in *WinRAR*. So although the total number of bytes is more than 10 times of dictionary size, the solid compression is nevertheless impressive. The RAR archive file can be made even smaller by using RAR5 format and use a dictionary size of 64 MB resulting in a file size of 163 KB for the solid RAR archive file.

But **solid** compression of *WinRAR* is **not** designed **for** compressing similar very **large files**.

The technique to best compress such files is first putting all those files into a single archive file using **store** for *compression method*, i.e. producing one huge file with uncompressed data. Then this huge archive file is compressed using normal, good or even best compression without creating a solid archive.

**Note:** By default *WinRAR* just stores files containing usually already compressed data in an archive file. So after selecting the huge RAR archive with data of all files just stored in the archive and clicking on button **Add**, it is necessary to remove on tab **Files** the file name pattern *.rar from list of *files to store without compression* to get the selected huge RAR archive file compressed into final RAR archive file.

But if this technique works and makes sense for your 15 GB+ files depends on file data, available free storage media size and available free memory size.